# Convert a .csv file into a specified style with Python by jupyter

Tags: python

The file looks like: [image: The file looks like]

The first column is `user_id`, and the second is the rating for `joke 1`, and the rest can be done in the same manner. I want to convert the file shown above into the format likes:

```
user_id | joke_id | rating
--------------------------
   1    |   1     | -7.82
   1    |   2     | 8.79
```

In addition, after conversion, as the normal ratings are between -10 and +10, the number 99 means the user didn't rate for the corresponding jokes and should be removed.

Comment: You need to show some effort on your part. Please post some code that you would have tried, and please provide the data in format users can use to run your code. Here you're just laying out your problem and expecting others to solve it for you. That's not what we do on this platform

Answer (score 0):

Your question involves several steps, please avoid mixing all questions into one. Based on your question, following steps would be helpful:

- **Reead `csv` file using `pandas`**

```
import pandas as pd
raw = pd.read_csv('PATH-TO-FILE')
```

- **Use `melt` to unpivot the `DataFrame`**

Because only the image is provided, will use a sample DataFrame instead.

```
raw = pd.DataFrame([[1, -7, 8, 99], [2, 4, 0, 6]], columns = ['user_id', 'joke_1', 'joke_2', 'joke_3'])
```

```
   user_id  joke_1  joke_2  joke_3
0        1      -7       8      99
1        2       4       0       6
```

Unpivot DataFrame using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(raw, id_vars=['user_id'], value_vars=['joke_1', 'joke_2', 'joke_3'], var_name='joke', value_name='rating')
```

```
   user_id    joke  rating
0        1  joke_1      -7
1        2  joke_1       4
2        1  joke_2       8
3        2  joke_2       0
4        1  joke_3      99
5        2  joke_3       6
```

- **Filter the Dataframe with condition**

With `pandas`, you can easily filter DataFrame with condition:

```
df_processed = df[df.rating != 99].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Please notice the `reset_index()` is used to clean the index, not related to your question.

Hope above would help.

Comment: So in this line: raw = pd.DataFrame([[1, -7, 8, 99], [2, 4, 0, 6]], columns = ['user_id', 'joke_1', 'joke_2', 'joke_3']), if I have 150 jokes, I need to add from 'joke_1' to 'joke_150', is that right?

Comment: Hi @ user15781190, the reason I used the code to create the `raw` DataFrame is I don't have the code to generate your initial data. In case you have the `csv` file, you can refer to my first point:
`import pandas as pd`
`raw = pd.read_csv('PATH-TO-FILE')`

Then you will be able to have the initial DataFrame.